# ReferenceError: config is not defined - Node Login Authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am new to nodejs and I am follow [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local#toc-database-config-configdatabasejs%22this%22) link for a simple login authentication but however as I am trying to follow up process I have configured a local mongodb database and as per the instructions I have updated the *database.js* file like -->

> config/database.js
>
> module.exports = {
>
> 'mongodb': '//localhost/loginApp'
>
> };

but however when I try to run

> node server.js

I am getting error as follows
[image]

can Someone help ?! I cant understand what is the issue with it ?!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like that you have this `config/database.js` in line 1 in your `database.js` file.

This should be commented out like `//config/database.js`. So Your code should be like

```
//config/database.js

module.exports = {

'mongodb': '//localhost/loginApp'

};
```